# How to create block with patameters? ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I create block like this:

1) Define your own completion block,

```
 typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);
```

2) Create a method which takes your completion block as a parameter,

```
-(void) myMethod:(myCompletion) compblock{
//do stuff
compblock(YES);
}
```

3)This is how you use it,

```
[self myMethod:^(BOOL finished) {
if(finished){
    NSLog(@"success");
}
}];
```

How can I send array in block and then get new array from block?

---

```
  //here I get array of image id's and go in loop for download it all,

NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", requestString];
NSURL * url  = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    userWithImage = [responseObject copy];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[requestOperation start];

//here I save it to mutable array and send as completion block,
```

yep, I think it will be better to send 1 image id and return in block 1 image. And in method there I will call the block - make action with photo separately. so, Is it possible to do?
I can do something like this with NSNotifications, but it will be more widely when it can be in blocks..

Comment: Are you trying to add an array as the parameter of the block? Just add it to the argument list: `BOOL finished, NSArray *myArray`.

Comment: @bdesham , How can I send array in block and then get new array from block?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Could you give more details about what exactly you’re trying to do?

Comment: I want sent array of image id's in block, inside it I go throw id's with loop and download images with AFNetworking, as it finished I send back array with images

Comment: What does one of your AFNetworking requests look like?

Comment: @Paul.s, like block, yes, it will block in block

Comment: That literally makes no sense. Can I see an example of the AFNetworking request that you are using

Comment: @Paul.s, look at first post

Comment: Your question is very poorly phrased and doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to write a wrapper around the `AFNetworking` request you could write a method like this:

```
- (void)downloadImageWithPath:(NSString *)path completion:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, UIImage *image, NSError *error))completion __attribute__((nonnull(2)));
{
  NSParameterAssert(completion);

  NSURL        *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
  NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
  requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

  [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    completion(operation, responseObject, nil);
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    completion(operation, nil, error);
  }];

  [requestOperation start];
}
```

You would invoke this with something like:

```
[self downloadImageWithPath:@"http://url/to/image.jpg"
                 completion:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                   if (error) {
                     // handle error
                     return;
                   }

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     // Update UI with image
                   });
                 }];
```

Comment: you my god!! it works like I need!! It is very cool, Paul. How can I learn this technic?  And how it named?

Comment: There is nothing special about this technique it's just using blocks. Just read and write as many sample methods that use blocks and you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 4):

1) Define your own completion block

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL finished, NSArray *myArray);
```

2) Create a method which takes your completion block as a parameter,

```
-(void)myMethod:(myCompletion)compblock {
    //do stuff
    NSArray *myArray = ...;
    compblock(YES, myArray);
}
```

3)This is how you use it,

```
[self myMethod:^(BOOL finished, NSArray *myArray) {
    if (finished){
        NSLog(@"success");
    }
}];
```

Comment: How can I send array in block and then get new array from block?